# VBA Convert DOM Document to string

Tags: xml, vba, dom

I have a DOM document loaded with:

```
Set XMLSample = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
XMLSample.LoadXML(C:\Sample.xml)
```

I found ways to convert the loaded DOM Document (XMLSample) to a string variable, not a text file (inverse load) in java and php, but is there any way to do it in VBA?

Need it to store "undo" documents.

Answer (score 2):

To load XML content from a file, you must use the Load method, not LoadXML. LoadXML is used to load XML content from a string.

To get XML content from a DOM Document, you may use the xml property.

```
Sub Test()
    Set XMLSample = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
        XMLSample.Load "C:\Users\OlegB\Sample.xml"
    Dim text As String
        text = XMLSample.XML
    Debug.Print text
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
Apologize for my very bad english